# Ruby on rails mysql searches

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am totally new to Ruby on Rails and I am trying to search through some relational database tables, I am trying to search for a given ID number in a Customer table then from the results look at who the sales_rep for that customer is. With this

```
@salesrepcust = Customer.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = ?",@data])
```

I am able to get back the correct customer given there ID number but I dont see how in ruby on rails to then pull from those results just one column value, in this it would be the value for sales_rep, and then use that as my @result for

```
@salesrepcustdata = Salesrep.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = ?", @result])
```

I have searched for this but i guess im not wording it correctly because i am not able to find anything specifically on this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward to select a single column; you can try something like this:

```
@salesrepcustids = Customer.where(id: @data).select(:id)
```

This will generate a `SELECT id FROM ...` statement.

And now you can do this:

```
@salesrepcustdata = Salesrep.where(id: @salesrepcustids)
```

This will generate an `SELECT...IN` statement with those ids.

(You might find it easier to set up proper ActiveRecord `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships in your models, or whatever relationship is appropriate.)

Comment: I am getting a compile error when trying to use that code compile error
/rails1/app/views/example/salesrepdisplay.html.erb:21: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
     @salesrepcust = Customer.where(id: @data).select(:id) 
I tried swtich around the : on the first id which give me
undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x7fb8ba52dc60>

Comment: That's odd. What versions of ruby/rails are you using? The shorthand hash syntax should be available in any version of ruby post 1.9.x. Also, do your models inherit from ActiveRecord::Base?

Comment: Just to clarify "shorthand hash syntax", for instance, change `id: @data` to `:id => @data`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sales rep is represented in the `Customer` table as `sales_rep_id` you can just do:

```
Salesrep.find(Customer.find(@data).sales_rep_id)
```

The `find` method assumes you're looking for `id` and if there's just one item with that `id`, there's no need to specify `:all`.

This is all discussed in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

That Customer query could be simplified to just:

```
@customer = Customer.find(@data)
```

You don't mention if you've setup a relationship between Customer and Salesrep but here goes:

```
# app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :salesrep, class_name: 'Salesrep' # => the customers table should have a salesrep_id column
end

# app/models/salesrep.rb
class Salesrep < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers
end

customer_id = 1
@customer = Customer.find(customer_id)
@salesrep = @customer.salesrep

# from the other way, assuming you need both the salesrep and customer:
salesrep_id = 10
@salesrep = Salesrep.find(salesrep_id)
# the following will only find the customer if it's owned by the Salesrep
@customer = @salesrep.customers.find(customer_id)
```